# Asymptotic length of reduced word on free group with replacements

Tags: probability, group-theory, reference-request, free-groups, combinatorics-on-words

This seems to be an elementary question, but it's proving hard for me to just Google. Suppose you have a sequence which picks elements out of $\{a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}, c, c^{-1}\}$ with equal probability. After, say, seven steps you'll get words like $a b c c^{-1} a c b^{-1} $ which in this case reduces to $a b a c  b^{-1} $ after canceling inverses. My question is this: if I write $c$ as some string of $a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}$, (and write $c^{-1}$ as the inverse of that) are there any theorems about the expected length of the new sequence after reduction? For example, I could take $c = a^{-1} b b$ so my previous word becomes just $ab b$. I care mostly about the case of a very long word.

Comment: You are looking at a random walk on a tree. It is known that such a walk tends to infinity linearly. The statement holds more generally for random walks on hyperbolic groups.

Comment: @Seirios Right, so clearly the sequence of $\{a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}, c, c^{-1}\}$ (where each happens with probability $1/6$) goes to infinity at a rate $(5/6)(1) + (1/6)(-1) = 2/3$. But I'm wondering what happens when I replace $c$ with a function of $a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}$. If I write $c = a b^{-1} a$, then I'm taking a random walk on $\{a, a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}, a b^{-1} a, a^{-1} b a^{-1}\}$, where each of those six elements still happens with probability $1/6$. But this sequence grows faster than $2/3$ - my question is how much faster?

Comment: Does the word $aba^{-1}$ reduce to $b$, i.e., do the letters commute?

Comment: @toliveira No, nothing commutes here. Well except $a a^{-1} = a^{-1} a = 1$ and such.

Answer (score 5):

The keywords are *random walks on (hyperbolic) groups* and *speed of escape*. There are many references on the subject (e.g. [this one](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~jquint/publications/CoursChili.pdf), although it's likely to be too general for your problem), and the precise result you seem to be interested in is a theorem by Kesten (1959).

**Setting**

Let $F_2$ be the free group on two generators. Let us consider a sequence of i.i.d. $F_2$-valued random variables $(X_k)$, with $\mathbb{P} (X_0 = d) = 1/6$ for $d\in \{a,a^{-1}, b, b^{-1}, c, c^{-1}\}$ (replace $c$ by any word in $a$, $b$ you like). Note that the $X_k$'s are symmetric: $X_k^{-1}$ has the same distribution as $X_k$, and the support of their distribution generates $F_2$.

Define a random walk on $F_2$ by taking $S_0 := e$, and $S_{n+1} = X_n S_n$.

The group $F_2$ is endowed with the word metric, that is $d(e, g)$ is the length of the shortest way to write $g$ as a product of the generators $a$, $b$ and their inverses. What you are interested in is $d(e, S_n)$.

**Observations**

Note that $d(e, S_{n+m}) \leq d(e, S_n)+d(e, S_m)$. Hence, the stochastic process $(d(e, S_n))_{n \geq 0}$ is subadditive. Some general results of ergodic theory (e.g. [Kingman's subbaditive theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingman%27s_subadditive_ergodic_theorem) which is a generalization of the law of large numbers) tells you that there is a real $\ell \geq 0$ such that, almost surely,

$$\ell = \lim_{n \to + \infty} \frac{d(e, S_n)}{n}.$$

Not that this is true for any discrete group (with a left-invariant metric) and any random walk with bounded steps. However, the limit can easily be $0$; indeed, if you take a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^d$, then the central limit theorem tells you that $d(e, S_n)$ is of the order of $\sqrt{n}$, and thus grow sub-linearly.

**(Non)-amenable groups**

At this point, it is useful to distinguish between two kind of groups: those which are [*amenable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group), and those which are not. While there are many equivalent definitions, I'll just give two criteria:

- if a discrete group has polynomial (or sub-exponential) growth, then it is amenable. For instance, a ball of radius $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ has $\sim n^d$ elements, so $\mathbb{Z}^d$ has polynomial growth.
- If a discrete group contains a copy of $F_2$ as a subgroup, then it is not amenable.

**A theorem of Kesten**

It turns out that non-amenability is exactly what we need to get a linear rate of growth!

> **Theorem** (Kesten)
>
> Let $G$ be a finitely generated group. Let $(S_n) = (X_{n-1} \ldots X_0)$ be a random walk on $G$. Let $\mu \in \mathcal{P} (G)$ be the distribution of $X_0$. Assume that the support of $\mu$ is bounded, and generates $G$. Assume furthermore that the random walk is symmetric, i.e.  $X_0 \equiv X_0^{-1}$ in distribution. Then $\ell >0$ if and only if $G$ is non-amenable.

Your problem fits perfectly this framework. In other word, no matter what $c$ you choose, almost surely, the length of the reduced words shall grow linearly (with a speed $\ell$ which depends only on $c$).

I guess that the next step would be to find $\ell$ as a function of $c$, and even get a more elementary proof for given (not too long) $c$. That said, before going to the specifics, I believe that a rough picture of the general theory is useful.

Comment: Thanks. Does this give me any hope of actually computing $\ell$ though? That's really the hard part, isn't it? Finding $d(e, S_n)$ doesn't seem to be any more feasible than doing the multinomial expansion of $(a + a^{-1} + b + b^{-1} + a b^{-1} + b a^{-1})^n$ (or whatever) and counting the occurrences of words of a given length.

Comment: @Mr. G: My best guess is that the first three letters of $S_n$ converge for large $n$ to a stationary distribution. Computing this distribution should be feasible, and getting $\ell$ from this distribution should be easy (because the average length gained from $S_n$ to $S_{n+1}$ depends on the first three letters of $S_n$ and on $X_n$, so you only have to average among all possibilities). I don't know if this idea can be made rigorous.

Comment: I think you're exactly right about the stationary distribution. The problem was that it seemed impossible to find the distribution as the fixed point of a recurrence relation. Say $c = a b^{-1}$ and say you consider the twelve possible values of $aa, ab, a b^{-1}$ etc. as your "states." The probability of transitioning to any state at step $n + 1$ depends on the first four letters of your current word (because you can remove $0, 1$ or $2$ at each step). But those four letters don't have to be the $n$ and $n - 1$ states; that information could have been lost if you just went backwards.